# Save File to .txt after finishing operation

Tags: c#

I already got most of the help I needed in order to create a working button to save my scraped proxies to a .txt file, but I still run into one issue. This is the code that I have gotten so far, it works perfectly fine:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace CyberScraper
{
    public partial class Base_Scraper : Form
    {
        WebClient _WC = new WebClient();
        Defaults _DF = new Defaults();
        public Base_Scraper()
        {
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Base_Scraper_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("twitch.tv/CyberLost same YT Name");
        }

        private void ScrapeTheProxies()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string Source in ScrapeSources.Lines)
                {
                    string UnparsedWebSource = _WC.DownloadString(Source);

                    MatchCollection _MC = _DF.REGEX.Matches(UnparsedWebSource);
                    foreach (Match Proxy in _MC)
                    {
                        GatheredProxies.Items.Add(Proxy);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        private void SaveProxyResults_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream;
            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.Title = "";
            dlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop";
            dlg.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            dlg.FilterIndex = 1;
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = dlg.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    myStream.Close();
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dlg.FileName);

                    for (int i = 0; i < GatheredProxies.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine((string)GatheredProxies.Items[i]);
                    }

                    writer.Close();
                }

            }

            dlg.Dispose();
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrapeTheProxies();
        }

        private void ScrapeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on "Save Results" it works before I scraped the proxies, if I do it after finishing scraping the proxies it outputs this error and saves it on the desktop as an empty .txt file instead of a .txt file containing the scraped proxies:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to type 'System.String'.'

in:

```
writer.WriteLine((string)GatheredProxies.Items[i]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to get out of the regex matches? You need to get that information out of each match. Try: `writer.WriteLine(GatheredProxies.Items[i].ToString());`

Comment: The error is telling you the cast can't be done, but since all objects have a `ToString` method, you might try that instead.

Comment: No more error

But it still outputs it as a blank .txt file after it's done. Do I maybe need to add a Stop button so it knows the task of scraping the proxies is finished?